How to handle global SCSS variables with `@use` when migrating from `@import`?
I'm migrating my SCSS files from @import to @use, as @import is being deprecated. I have a mixin defined in a separate file that relies on a global SCSS variable. Here's an example:
// mixin.scss
@mixin bg {
  background: $bg;
}

The $bg variable is globally defined. With @import, this works because the variable is accessible globally. However, when switching to @use, global variables are no longer directly accessible. I need to explicitly import the file where the variable is defined, like this:
// mixin.scss
@use "theme/primary" as theme;

@mixin bg {
  background: theme.$bg;
}

The challenge is that my project uses multiple themes, and the specific theme is determined dynamically at build time. This means I cannot statically import a specific theme file into mixin.scss.
With @import, I could globally import the theme variables and mixin files, making them accessible throughout the app. How can I achieve similar functionality with @use, considering @import will eventually be removed?
